# Como hacer que los datos Google Analytics coincida con la API

Tags: python, api, google-analytics

Tengo una `Api` en `Python` para descargarme datos de `Google Analytics` con una dimensión personalizada.

Al bajarme los datos veo que no coinciden con los que tengo en `GA`. La muestra que estoy seleccionando en los campos date son del 1 al 31 del mes de Julio y hay mas de 3.000.000 de registros. No puedo *granular* más y he de reportar los *users*.

Hay alguna forma de hacer que los datos me coincidan con lo que tengo en `Google Analytics`?.

He visto que hay una restricción a la hora de trabajar con los registros en las dimensiones personalizadas.

```
def query_analytics(service, profile_id, start_date, end_date):
    if profile_id == None or profile_id == "0":
        profile_id = get_first_profile_id(service)
    result = service.data().ga().get(
        ids='ga:' + profile_id,
        start_date='2021-07-01',
        end_date='2021-07-31',
        filters='ga:dimension7==patata',
        metrics='ga:' + 'users'
    ).execute()
    return result
```

Comment: Dinos primero qué API estás usando. GA lanzó una nueva API llamada [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) y, para GA 4, parece que la API será [Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1). ¿Estás usando Core Reporting, o Data API o la vieja API de GA (no recomendable)?

Comment: Buenas A. Cedano, estoy usando la 'v3' si es a eso a lo que te refieres,(soy nuevo en esto). "service = discovery.build('analytics', 'v3', http_auth)" es lo que uso en la función create_Service_object. MUchismias gracias

Comment: La `v3` es la vieja. [Yo tuve problemas con ella](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1772) usando el cliente de PHP (no sé si el problema era específico de ese cliente, supongo que no, que era de GA en sí mismo). El problema en mi caso era que la v3 no contaba las vistas anteriores a una fecha dada. Fue en ese reporte donde la misma gente de Google me sugirió que usara Reporting API.

Comment: [En la página de la v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=es) hay una nota, casi al principio, donde te advierten de que hay una nueva versión de la API, que es precisamente Reporting API. Si estás teniendo problemas con la v3 puede que sea debido a errores en dicha API, si es eso, no podrás resolverlos de otro modo que migrando a la última versión, lo cual es recomendable porque de todos modos, aunque resuelvas este problema en este punto, seguir usando una versión obsoleta te seguirá causando problemas.

Comment: Buneas A.Cedano, he migrado ya a la v4 ... y me sigue pasando lo mismo, entiendo que estoy usando la de reporting ya que me pone"https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest" . No sé que hacer

Comment: Revisa la página de referencia de la API, pues en la v4 han cambiado muchas cosas, entre ellas la forma en que creas el cliente, la forma de pasar los filtros y las dimensiones. Al menos en PHP era así, supongo que en Phyton también. En la página de referencia, tienes que ver [la sección para Phyton](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py). Allí te explican cómo hacer el upgrade (si no lo has hecho) y hay ejemplos de código sobre cómo se deben escribir las consultas.

Comment: Lanzando ese mismo report exacto en Query Explorer qué resultado te da? Te difiere también ahí?

Comment: Buenas, lanzando con el Query Explorer ... me da lo mismo, es decir, sigue sin coincidir. Decir que en la "query" pone v3

Comment: @ManuelDenegriRebaza, 100% de seguridad que es exactamente el mismo report? el profile ID es el mismo? no estarás recuperando los datos de una vista que no es la misma?

Comment: Buenas, perdonad por la tardanza, me sale lo mismo en. En cuanto al profile ID, sí, es el mismo